# Nginx alternative for key/value store with Nginx Plus

Tags: nginx

I am working with Nginx Open Source but would like to use the key/value store module which is available for Nginx Plus. Does anyone know if there is an alternative that I could use with Nginx Open Source.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/kjdev/nginx-keyval:

> This nginx module creates variables with values taken from key-value pairs.
>
> This modules is heavenly inspired by the nginx original http_keyval_module.